# chef-client not starting with chef-client cookbook RHEL 6.7

Tags: ruby, chef-infra, rhel

I am using the 4.3.2 chef-client cookbook, chef-client 12.6, and my run list is - role chef-client, and my chef-client role is as follows: 
chef-client
chef-client::config
chef-client::delete_validation

Link to the cookbook - https://github.com/chef-cookbooks/chef-client

My os is rhel 6.7

Also, if it matters, I am using Packer to create the image when this issue occurs.

I log-on to the VM, and I am unable to start the service either. 
During the chef-client run, it will error with the following 

`` 'mazon-ebs: ================================================================================
    amazon-ebs: Error executing action `start` on resource 'service[chef-client]'
    amazon-ebs: ================================================================================
    amazon-ebs:
    amazon-ebs: Mixlib::ShellOut::ShellCommandFailed
    amazon-ebs: ------------------------------------
    amazon-ebs: Expected process to exit with [0], but received '6'
    amazon-ebs: ---- Begin output of /sbin/service chef-client start ----
    amazon-ebs: STDOUT:
    amazon-ebs: STDERR:
    amazon-ebs: ---- End output of /sbin/service chef-client start ----
    amazon-ebs: Ran /sbin/service chef-client start returned 6
    amazon-ebs:
    amazon-ebs: Resource Declaration:
    amazon-ebs: ---------------------
    amazon-ebs: # In /var/chef/cache/cookbooks/chef-client/recipes/init_service.rb
    amazon-ebs:
    amazon-ebs: 32: service 'chef-client' do
    amazon-ebs: 33:   supports :status => true, :restart => true
    amazon-ebs: 34:   action [:enable, :start]
    amazon-ebs: 35: end
    amazon-ebs:
    amazon-ebs: Compiled Resource:
    amazon-ebs: ------------------
    amazon-ebs: # Declared in /var/chef/cache/cookbooks/chef-client/recipes/init_service.rb:32:in `from_file'
    amazon-ebs:
    amazon-ebs: service("chef-client") do
    amazon-ebs: action [:enable, :start]
    amazon-ebs: updated true
    amazon-ebs: supports {:status=>true, :restart=>true}
    amazon-ebs: retries 0
    amazon-ebs: retry_delay 2
    amazon-ebs: default_guard_interpreter :default
    amazon-ebs: service_name "chef-client"
    amazon-ebs: enabled true
    amazon-ebs: pattern "chef-client"
    amazon-ebs: declared_type :service
    amazon-ebs: cookbook_name "chef-client"
    amazon-ebs: recipe_name "init_service"
    amazon-ebs: end
    amazon-ebs:
    amazon-ebs: [2016-01-20T16:49:04-05:00] INFO: Running queued delayed notifications before re-raising exception
    amazon-ebs: [2016-01-20T16:49:04-05:00] INFO: template[/etc/init.d/chef-client] sending restart action to service[chef-client] (delayed)
    amazon-ebs: * service[chef-client] action restart[2016-01-20T16:49:04-05:00] INFO: Processing service[chef-client] action restart (chef-client::init_service line 32)
    amazon-ebs:
    amazon-ebs:
    amazon-ebs: ================================================================================
    amazon-ebs: Error executing action `restart` on resource 'service[chef-client]'
    amazon-ebs: ================================================================================
    amazon-ebs:
    amazon-ebs: Mixlib::ShellOut::ShellCommandFailed
    amazon-ebs: ------------------------------------
    amazon-ebs: Expected process to exit with [0], but received '6'
    amazon-ebs: ---- Begin output of /sbin/service chef-client restart ----
    amazon-ebs: STDOUT: Stopping chef-client: [FAILED]
    amazon-ebs: STDERR:
    amazon-ebs: ---- End output of /sbin/service chef-client restart ----
    amazon-ebs: Ran /sbin/service chef-client restart returned 6
    amazon-ebs:
    amazon-ebs: Resource Declaration:
    amazon-ebs: ---------------------
    amazon-ebs: # In /var/chef/cache/cookbooks/chef-client/recipes/init_service.rb
    amazon-ebs:
    amazon-ebs: 32: service 'chef-client' do
    amazon-ebs: 33:   supports :status => true, :restart => true
    amazon-ebs: 34:   action [:enable, :start]
    amazon-ebs: 35: end
    amazon-ebs:
    amazon-ebs: Compiled Resource:
    amazon-ebs: ------------------
    amazon-ebs: # Declared in /var/chef/cache/cookbooks/chef-client/recipes/init_service.rb:32:in from_file
     amazon-ebs:
    amazon-ebs: service("chef-client") do
    amazon-ebs: action [:enable, :start]
    amazon-ebs: updated true
    amazon-ebs: supports {:status=>true, :restart=>true}
    amazon-ebs: retries 0
    amazon-ebs: retry_delay 2
    amazon-ebs: default_guard_interpreter :default
    amazon-ebs: service_name "chef-client"
    amazon-ebs: enabled true
    amazon-ebs: pattern "chef-client"
    amazon-ebs: declared_type :service
    amazon-ebs: cookbook_name "chef-client"
    amazon-ebs: recipe_name "init_service"
    amazon-ebs: end
    amazon-ebs:
    amazon-ebs: ``

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using the `chef-client` cookbook you should put this in your run list: `chef-client::config, chef-client:init_service`.

Avoid putting `chef-client` in your run list before including the `config`, because [this will create the service before creating the configuration](https://github.com/chef-cookbooks/chef-client/blob/v4.3.2/recipes/default.rb#L20).

So, remove `chef-client::default` (aka `chef-client`) from your run list. That's all. You can use `chef-client::config, chef-client::default, chef-client::delete_validation` if you prefer. But remember, the config goes first.

Comment: Ah okay. That makes sense. You also explained it VERY well. Thanks!